# Is it ok to change a JavaScript file name by changing it's writable property descriptor?

Tags: javascript, forms

I need to change a file's name before uploading it but the property is readonly:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

so

```
this.imageFile.name = newFileName;
```

doesnt work.

I looked at other questions here but the answers are all - 'create a new file using the File contructor'.

eg

```
var file = new File(['foo'], 'newName', {type:'img/jpg'});
```

But the constructor is not available in IE or edge.

In the end I found form data has good support on caniuse.com and you can provide a new file name like so:

```
var newFileName = file.filename + "new";
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file, newFileName);
```

In between these two solutions, I tried another:

```
Object.defineProperty(this.imageFile, 'name', {
     writable: true
});

this.imageFile.name = newFileName;
```

Clearly this one is a hack, but it worked. I decided not to go with this as FormData append method takes a filename to solve this problem, I just dont understand why it is a readonly property if I can manually change the descriptor and it works fine.

Comment: Yours is a legitimate question, but is there any reason you can't do this on the backend?

Comment: Backend just isnt designed that way and its a service being used by many front end clients

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just dont understand why it is a readonly property...

Because [specification](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#file-section) says so:

> User agents should endeavor to have a File object’s snapshot state set to the state of the underlying storage on disk at the time the reference is taken.

```
interface File : Blob {
  readonly attribute DOMString name;
  readonly attribute long long lastModified;
};
```

The `name` attribute represents current file name, so it doesn't make sense to have an ability to change it in the `File` object.

Although, when you're sending this file's content to the server with `FormData.append()` with 3rd parameter, this action doesn't change file state nor an underlying storage it represents.